# How to draw roc curve from roc given tpr, fpr and thres in matlab without using plotroc function?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, roc

I am having difficulty in drawing roc curve from given roc matrix.
I am using following code:

```
>> t = [0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1];
>> o = [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1];
>> [tpr,fpr,thres] = roc(t,o);
```

Now I need to draw roc curve from these values without using plotroc function in matlab. I tried to use

```
plot(tpr,fpr);
```

but this is not showing same result as `plotroc(t,o)`. Is there any other alternate way to do this?